# How should I transport Cannondale Bad Boy 5 INSIDE a BMW 4 Series Coupe?

Tags: cannondale, transportation, transport-by-car

So, I have a Cannondale [Bad Boy 5](http://www.cannondale.com/2014/bikes/recreation-urban/urban/bad-boy/bad-boy-5) and I'm *LOVING* it.

[image: bike]

I'd like to understand how to transport it. I have 2014 BMW 4 Series coupe. Even though I folded back seats (to maximize trunk storage), bike won't fit there (well at least not all the way anyway), so I gotta take one of the wheel off. The wheels are 700c discs and the fork is a Cannondale Lefty fork (i.e. attaches only on one side).

my main concern is since i cannot easily take off front wheel due to lefty fork and i can use quick release to take the rear wheel off; What's better way to handle derailleur (without ruining your cloth, car, etc).

Ideally I'd like to:

- use quick release to remove rear wheel,
- place chain into some sort of container (suggestions?),
- place bike along with separated wheel (derailleur up) inside of the car,
- go to wherever, and revert procedure.

Comment: There's always the bike hanging out of the trunk approach.

Comment: What is the problem with taking one of the wheels off?

Comment: @Blam - The front wheel is using a special axle and doesn't come off readily.  Removing the back is messy -- some scheme would have to be developed to control the chain.  And removing wheels on disk brake bikes is always a bit touchy.

Comment: @DanielRHicks That was a question for alexus that he answered in an edit to his question 3 hours ago.   Not a questions that I was asking for myself.

Comment: Removing the chain frequently is not a good idea even if running a master link, the links have the tendency to become loose. You would need to hang the chain into some sort of holder. Removing the rear wheel is do-able, but certainly not as easy as removing the front wheel on most standard forks. You need to shift the chain as far to the right on the cassette as you can undo the qr then push the derailleur forward at the hanger (moving the body not just the cage). The wheel will fall off. There's a knack to it.

Comment: Also when removing wheels with disc brakes you need to be extra careful not to squeeze the brake lever or better still put a spacer in between the pads once the rotor is out.

Comment: @DWGKNZ - Getting the rear wheel off of a derailleur bike (without breaking the chain) is something many 12-year-olds can do.  The trick is to do it without getting grease all over your hands and everything else, and then keep the chain clean and undamaged while being transported.  For these reasons removing the rear wheel to transport is unattractive.

Comment: @DanielRHicks you'd be surprised at how many people struggle to do it!! Once you understand how to do it and get the knack it's easy to do without touching anything apart from the QR and RD. My point was it's not as easy as removing a normal front wheel.

Comment: Removing the back wheel may not save the space issue. When you remove the front wheel it lets you lie the handle bars flat. removing the backwheel leaves this height (600mm) on a flat bar sticking up.

Comment: You can afford a $40,000 car, but can't afford a $200 bike carrier?

Comment: Leave the car at home and just ride the bike?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the other answers deal with the OPs desire to keep the bike inside the car, i.e. not on a rack.

To put the bike in the car, you have to take off at least one of the wheels.

Pedro sells a "chain keeper" which is designed to keep the chain on or near the derailleur when the rear wheel is off:

[image: Pedro's chain keeper]
[image]

This should help you considerably (along with old towels and maybe a moving blanket) to put the bike cleanly in the car with the rear wheel off.

Comment: I have one, they are awesome for cleaning the chain when on a bike stand.

Answer (score 2):

If cannot fit the bike in you have four options:

1. Remove the front wheel and lower seat, this makes the bike much smaller.
   This is the no cost, no change to car and medium effort to get wheel off and on 
   and get bike in and out of car.
   [image]
2. Mount a roof rack and use a carrier.
   This is a medium cost, semi permanent (roof rack can be removed) and medium
   effort to get bike up and down.
   [image]
3. Install a trailer hitch or tow bar and use a hard mount rack.
   This is an expensive permanent solution if you don't have a trailer hitch 
   installed. You can remove rack however and bike is very easy to get on and off rack.
   [image]
4. Use a trunk mounted rack.
   This is a cheap temporary solution. Medium effort to mount rack on trunk easy
   to get bike on and off.

[image]

Comment: It may also be easier if you flatten the handlebars, but thats another annoying thing to have to re-setup (also, removing the rear wheel may help as well). The best option is normally to use a rack, just cause the hassle involved - roof racks increase drag and look ugly always and a trailer hitch on a BMW is normally a no-no, so a trunk rack is the way to go (and companies like Thule make nice ones). Note that you're more likely to scratch your car putting the bike inside than using a rack (but lower theft rate). Aside: On older BMW's, you used to have pay extra to get folding rear seats!

Comment: Also, a lot of roof mounts use the front fork as a mounting point - with a lefty fork, this means an additional adapter if your roof rack has a compatible one (Yakima and Thule seem to make them for their racks). And it should be noted that you can get a bit of security by getting a lock to the rack. But really, a coupe (especially a small one like the BMW 4 series coupe) is highly non-ideal for moving a bike (or really, anything more than 2 people)...

Comment: +1: Personally I find removing a wheel to install on roof racks or into the boot is a PITA. I agree with damage (and mud) to car using boot, and if you do it often enough eventually you will squish a finger.  Disc brake lever inevitably gets squished making it another PITA to install the wheel, unless you carry the shipping spacer with you which is a PITA on its own. That leaves roof rack like one pictured - which never gets removed so sucks petrol and a roof rack on a coupe - really.... Leaving trunk mount as the only viable option, especially for short trips.

Comment: As regards the first point, it is also possible to get carry bags for bikes (designed mainly for transporting the bike by air etc.), also smaller bags which just cover the chainrings and chain. Obviously these bags don't save space, but they might stop you crudding up your car.

Comment: @mattnz - I've got a boot mount and find that horrible to get on and off. I've got a big old hatchback which I use solely for carting my bike or the dog.

Comment: @PeteH In many cases also an old blanket to wrap the bike into does the job fairly well...

Comment: Adding a 1-1/4 inch trailer hitch *(without wiring)* to a modern car is not that expensive I paid $150 for mine. The actual bike carrier cost less than $100 and seems way more reliable than the trunk mounted systems. I can also still open my trunk with a bike on the rack.

Comment: One needs to be a little careful when getting a hitch receiver for use with a bike rack.  The rack produces a fairly substantial "lever arm", and if the hitch is not totally rigid and secure it can bend or poop off.  (And I think $400 is closer to a realistic price to get a hitch receiver installed.)

Comment: Most hitch based bike racks the bike will cover numberplate and lights. Many countrys require a light board therefore light wiring for the hitch. Check local regs, and if the Police enforce them (Where I live the often have campaigns on obscured number plates and lights)

Comment: @mattnz - I've never heard of anyone being hassled for having the license plate obscured by a bike rack in the US.  I'm sure there are a few tight-pantied cops Out East who might do this, but it would be rare.

Comment: @GaryE - Presumably you don't drive a brand new BMW.

Comment: @DanielRHicks in New Zealand if your number plate and lights are obscured you are required to display a supplementary number plate and light board which requires the same wiring and plug as for towing trailer.

Comment: @DWGKNZ -- Well, remember that anything in the US more than 50 miles west of the East Coast is the Wild West.

Comment: I have added hitch receivers to both my Audi and Infinity cars. The hitch installation is substantially cheaper when you specify no electrical wiring. In addition, with 1-1/4 inch hitches you need to purchase an aftermarket "locking pin" ($10). The locking pin bolts the bike rack to the hitch making the entire unit much stronger. Finally, hitches for modern cars are specific to each model car. There is essentially only a single hitch for an Audi A6. Don't get it installed by the car dealer, who probably installs 2 or 3 a year- go to a company that specializes in installing trailer hitches.

Comment: Hitch pin locking bolt: http://www.amazon.com/Curt-Manufacturing-22321-Anti-Rattle-Hollow/dp/B001EOWR3Y/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1404400725&sr=8-7&keywords=trailer+hitch+pin+lock+bolt

Comment: Voted down as the OP requested ways to transport the bike INSIDE the car.

Comment: @RoboKaren - that was a clarification the OP made after many people spent time trying to assist him with options.

Comment: @DW - thanks, didn't realize that and SE won't let me change my vote. My bad.

Comment: @RoboKaren : No, this doesn't answer the OP's question. But the OP was asking the *wrong* question.

Answer (score 2):

The BMW roof rack system can be found for ~120$ USD, and 140$ USD for the touring bike carrier.

Works extremely well.

[image: On my 1 series]

Answer (score 1):

If you literally mean inside then:
If you are going to remove a wheel and lefty makes front difficult.  Then remove the rear and place derailleur up and near rear of trunk.  Why place the chain in a container - just leave the chain on the bike. You still have dirt to deal with from front wheel but better than grease from derailleur and chain.  Get a rubber trunk mat.  Weathertech makes one for a BMW 4 Series Coupe.

I think it is bit conservative but Cannodale has some very specific recomendations regarding racks.

[14_Cannondale_Owners_Manual.pdf](http://media.cannondale.com/media/Manuals/14_Cannondale_Owners_Manual.pdf) 
See page 101 Type of rack design

[image: Cannondale Type OR Rack Design]

This is one rack that is wheel only
[YakimaFrontLoader](http://www.yakima.com/shop/bike/roof/frontloader)